# Problem analyzing diode circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxl8Wc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to find the voltage at node 3 considering all the diodes ideal. I tried the Superposition theorem to find the result.

When V2 will be shorted, then node 3 voltage should be 0 volts.

When V1 will be shorted, 'D2' will be turned off and the voltage at node 3 should be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{10}{10+5}10 = 6.667 (approximately)
\end{equation}

So, the voltage at node 3 should be 0+6.667= 6.667 volts. But the result is provided 3.3 volts (approximately).

I did a simulation too.(Diodes of simulation causes 0.27 volt drop)  [image]

So how do I solve it ?

Comment: Superposition applies to linear circuits. Be careful - if a diode is active with one supply, but inactive with the other supply, superposition fails. Safer to use other methods.

Comment: Oh .. I thought that superposition is applicable anywhere.

Comment: Superposition is only applicable to LTI (linear time-invariant) circuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspection, V1 and V2 in their shown position and polarity both will create a current flow through D1 and D2 will become reverse biased. This could have been different if R1 was 10 kohm and R2 was 5 kohm.

In other words, use your eyes and have a think before launching into a theorem that might not work with non-linear components.

So, now you know which "ideal" diode is conducting and which "ideal" diode isn't, throw them away and replace with either a short (conducting) or an open (non-conducting).

This leaves a very simple arrangement: -

[image]

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use source transformation.
[image]